# Using CSS :after to shade a button:hover

Tags: css, button

I'm trying to add a bunch of different color classes to my buttons and allow additional classes to be added arbitrarily.  All of these should darken on hover.  It seems tedious to write `button.(color):hover` rules for every single color, so I've written this such that the `:after` section gets darker and covers the button background.

http://jsfiddle.net/kjpczL5w/1/

However, I can't get the `:after` section to fit between the button's text and its background as desired.  At the moment, it also shades the text.  The idea here is to remove any tedious part of adding a new button element or a new button color class, so I'd like to avoid additional html or additional css rules for each color.  Ideas?

```css
button {
    border: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none;
}
button:after {
    content: " ";
    transition: background-color .3s ease;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
button:hover:after { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); }
button.green { background-color: #6c842e; color: #ffffff; }
button.red { background-color: #ff4444; color: #ffffff; }
```

```html
<button>Boop</button>
<button class="green">Boop</button>
<button class="red">Boop</button>
```

Comment: I can be quite easy with an extra <span> tag, but you said you prefer to avoid that, it's your choice, here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjpczL5w/2/) if you ever need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `box-shadows` ?

```css
button {
  border: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
}
button:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
button.green {
  background-color: #6c842e;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<button>Boop</button>
<button class="green">Boop</button>
```

Comment: Seems like a hack, but it works.  I'll wait and see if there's a less hacky answer before accepting yours.

Comment: This has the added benefit of a _really_ neat transition.